# Is it Possible to delete user account from Firrebase auth if user didn't verify email with in a fixed time in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Actually i want do  it in this way when user sign up with fake email. user can't verify this email.So the email should automatically deleted from firebase authentication after fixed time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase Authentication to auto-delete accounts like that. I'd also consider what you actually gain by such functionality, as the user can just recreate their Firebase Authentication account by calling the same API again.

You'll typically either want to:

- disable their account, which prevents them from signing in/signing up with it. This can be done through the Firebase Admin SDK, by first [getting a list of all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), and then [disabling the relevant ones](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).
- only grant them access to your back-end services if they've verified their email address (within a certain amount of time). How to do this depends on your backend services though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...
Now I managed to create something like after verifying email user can create his/her account